# if hibernate can generate the db schema, how to tell it to create a column of nvarchar(max)?

Tags: hibernate

if hibernate can generate the db schema, how to tell it to create a column of nvarchar(max) in a sql server db?

what tools are available to go the other way around, i.e. a tool that reads the database schema and outputs POJO's with annotations?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way I know of to use the maximum value for varchar when using Hibernate to generate a database schema. Even if you could this would probably be a bad idea since your code would behave differently with different databases instead of having a default length it's expecting for a given field. As far as reverse engineering goes check out [this link](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2009/02/reverse-engineering-sql-anywhere-with-hibernate-tools-part-trois/) to use Hibernate tools to reverse engineer a database from with in Eclipse, or see [this link](http://www.factorypattern.com/howto-generate-hibernate-pojo-and-mapping-files-using-ant-from-a-db-schema/) for a way to reverse engineer the database schema using Ant.